# Lisp Function fails, although working previously (Draft Sight, SVG to CAD)

Tags: svg, lisp, cad, autolisp

We are trying to implement a Draft Sight/AutoCad script that will transform a SVG file into a CAD drawing.

The principal idea is to read the file line by line (performed by ReadSVGData), split the svg definitions by spaces (ReadHTMLItemData), read the individual HTML attributes into a list and based on the type of the SVG item draw a CAD element. So much in regards to the principal...

The unususal part is, that whenever the Html Attributes, like "id="Box_8_0"" are sent to the findchar function, by attrlis function, the script fails, although the same arrangement went well before

Does anybody have a hint where my mistake is hidden?

```
(defun findchar (FindChar Text) 

    (setq
        ;current location in string
        coord 1
        ;Init Return Coordinate
        ReturnCoord 0
        ;Length of Searched Item, to enable string searching
        FindCharLen (strlen FindChar)
        ;Nil Count: Requires as regular expressions like (/t) are identified as two times ascii char 9
        NilCnt 0
        ;Storage of last Char Ascii to identify regular expressions
        LastCharAsci -1
    )

    ;iterate the String and break in case of the first occurence
    (while (and (<= coord (strlen Text) ) (= ReturnCoord 0))
        ;Current Character
        (setq CurChar (substr Text coord FindCharLen))

        ;Find Searched String
        (if (= FindChar CurChar)
            (setq ReturnCoord coord)
        )

        ;Check for regular expression
        (if (and (= LastCharAsci 9) (= (ascii CurChar) 9))
            (setq NilCnt (+ NilCnt 1))
        )

        ;Update String position and String
        (setq LastCharAsci (ascii CurChar))
        (setq coord (+ coord 1))
    )
    ;return variable
    (- ReturnCoord NilCnt)
)


(defun attrlis (HTMLAttr)
    (setq Koordi 0)




    (progn
        (setq CharLoc (findchar "<" HTMLAttr))

        (princ HTMLAttr)
        (terpri)
    )

    (+ Koordi 1)
)

(defun ReadHTMLItemData(HTMLItem)

    (setq 
        coord 1
        HTMLItmBgn 1
        Attributes 0
        CurChar 0
        Dictionary 0

    )

    ;(princ HTMLItem)
    ;(terpri)
    (while (<= coord (strlen HTMLItem))

        (setq CurChar (substr HTMLItem coord 1))
        (if (or (= (ascii CurChar) 32) (= (ascii CurChar) 62))
            (progn
                (if (> (- coord HTMLItmBgn) 0)
                    (progn
                        (setq htmlattr (substr HTMLItem HTMLItmBgn (- coord HTMLItmBgn)))

                        (setq Result (attrlis htmlattr))

                        (princ Result)

                        (setq HTMLItmBgn (+ coord 1))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        (setq coord (+ coord 1))
    )
)


(defun ReadLineContents(Line)
    (if (/= Line nil)
        (progn
            ;(princ Line)
            ;(terpri)

            (setq 

                Bgn (findchar "<" Line)
                End (findchar ">" Line)
                ItemDef (substr Line (+ Bgn (strlen "<"))  End)
            )

            (ReadHTMLItemData ItemDef)
        )
    )
)



(defun C:ReadSVGData()
    (setq SVGFile (open (getfiled "Select a file" "" "svg" 0) "r"))

    (setq Line 1)
    (while (/= Line nil)

        (setq Line (read-line SVGFile))
        (ReadLineContents Line)
    )

    (close SVGFile)

    (princ "Done")
)
```

Reading the following file:

```xml
<svg class="boxview" id="boxview" style="width:1198.56px; height:486.8004px; display:block;" viewBox="0 0 1198.56 486.8004">
<g id="BD_box">
    <rect class="box" id="Box_8_0" x="109.21" y="394.119" width="58.512" height="62.184" box="4047"></rect>
</g>
</svg>
```

**EDIT**

Change of substring Index, based on satraj's answer

Comment: "the script fails" could you be a bit more precise?

Comment: "the script fails", means DraftSight hangs completely and, except for shutting it down, no further options are left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the way the "substr" Autolisp function is used. The start index of **substr** always starts from index 1 (not from 0). So your code must be changed such that the start index are initialized as 1. The following lines in your code fails.

```
(setq CurChar (substr HTMLItem coord 1))

(setq htmlattr (substr HTMLItem HTMLItmBgn (- coord HTMLItmBgn)))
```

Since coord and HTMLItemBgn variables are initialized as 0, the substr function fails.

Also, why not use "**vl-string-search**" function if you want to find the position of a text in a string? you can get rid of the findchar function.

An Example:

```
(setq CharLoc (vl-string-search "<" HTMLAttr))
```

In general, if you want to debug failures in AutoLisp, add the following function to your lisp file and it will print a stack trace in case of failures, which will enable you to locate exact place where the error occured.

```
(defun *error* (msg)
(vl-bt)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the initialisation error. I have changed the now added a condition checking that there is a difference between the coord and HTMLItmBgn variable. The issue with the script failing remains  Whenever calling `(setq CharLoc (findchar "<" HTMLAttr))` in attrlis fails. When not calling findchar the output works fine.  The reference to the "vl-" comments is completely correct, but the issue is that the script is also supported to work in DraftSight, therefore all those nice commands are not available